# ASP.net configuration manager and outlook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configurationmanager

i have been requested to change the authentication mode in my mvc 4 project to be windows authentication, and i was using the asp.net configuration manager.
for us, it will be a major change in the code, so is there any workaround to link our outlook active directory to asp.net configuration manager ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following setting

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="EnableSimpleMembership" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

follow the link for more details

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/216/windows-authentication-with-asp-net-web-pages

Comment: Thanks for your help @Spider man, what i am asking for if there is any way to link asp.net config to active directory, i prefer not change our code